# User defined Quick Build command (sage) does not work in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu, sagetex

I use `LaTex` a lot in Ubuntu 14.04. Recently I came to know about the `sagetex` package and installed `sage-6.8-x86_64-Linux` . Suppose the tex file is `example.tex` , then one  has to run the following commanda to make it work.

```sh
pdflatex example.tex
sage example.sagetex.sage
pdflatex example.tex
```

Now I want to do run these commands from `Texmaker`. So I go to the menu  and then `Options → Configure → QuickBuild → User` and define there (in User) these three commands. I used the following pipeline

```sh
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | sage %.sagetex.sage | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

After that when I run `Quick Build` on the file from texmaker, I get a error message,

```
Error : could not start the command
```

I want to know why the Quick Build command does not work ? also if anyone could help me so that I could run those command from Texmaker.

Comment: Is there no other error message?  What happens when you only keep the first part `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` and remove the rest?

Comment: Nope. no other error message. It is fine when I run only the first command. Then it just do what `pdflatex` do. But after that a `example.sagetex.sage` file is created. Then I have to run the `sage` command on that file. At last again `pdflatex`. This is how `sagetex` works.

Comment: Your question seems similar to [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251870/how-do-i-write-a-custom-command-to-enable-sage-in-texmaker). In particular, make sure you read comments where the same error is given and two solutions: one works for me but not for Jason who leaves a comment (find "99%") about what he did to get it to work for him. Does it help? How is your problem different?

Comment: Hi @DJP. Thanks for your reply. After @Dan's idea, I have figured out whats was going wrong with my `Quickbuild` command. I have to write the whole path of the command `sage` in Texmaker. I replace my pipeline in `Options → Configure → QuickBuild → User` with `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | /home/ddas/sage-6.8-x86_64-Linux/sage %.sagetex.sage | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` . And that also worked for me. Thank you guys..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to work around this is to put all the commands you want into a script and just have Texmaker run the script. I downloaded Texmaker and got this working with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

pdflatex $1.tex && sage $1.sagetex.sage && pdflatex $1.tex
```

Make the script executable -- do `chmod a+x your-scripts-name` in a terminal -- and then in the Quick Build options, just put `/path/to/your-scripts-name %` . That worked for me.

One reason I like using a separate script is that I know exactly how it will work. Texmaker's use of the pipe character (`|`) to separate commands is a bit weird; if I put `&&` in the script, I know that if one command fails, it will not continue to try the other commands. This script will even work well for TeX files that don't use SageTeX: it will run the `pdflatex` command, then try the Sage command, which will fail because there's no .sagetex.sage file, and then the script will skip the second `pdflatex`.

Comment: Hi @Dan. Your method works for me. It is surely better to write our own script.