Latex & Sagetex
I hope this message finds you well. My name is Mario, and I am reaching out because I am experiencing persistent issues while trying to compile a LaTeX document on my Mac. The document in question integrates SageMath code to create a table, but I am encountering recurring problems during the compilation process(texstudio with Mactex)
I would greatly appreciate any advice or guidance on how to properly configure my setup to ensure smooth integration between LaTeX and Sage. Despite my efforts, the issues persist, and I am unsure how to resolve them effectively.
When compiling, I don't get any errors as such, other than the fact that where the Sage output should be, I get '??'. Obviously, I have Sage installed and the function works well in it, but when I move to LaTeX, it doesn't work.
I have tried adding certain compilation commands, but it still doesn't work. Sorry for the lack of detail, I didn't specify anything because I thought it would be something basic that could be resolved with a video or something similar.
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{sagetex} % Importa el paquete SageTeX

% Datos del documento

\title{Tabla de valores}

\author{}

\begin{document}

% Título del documento

\\maketitle



% Generación de tabla de valores

\\begin{sagesilent}

    \# Definimos la función para generar la tabla

    def tabla\_valores(fun, xi):

    n = len(xi)  # Número de puntos

    yi = \[\]      # Aquí almacenamos las coordenadas y

    for k in range(n):

    yi.append(fun.subs(x=xi\[k\]))  # Calculamos f(x) para cada xi

    

    \# Comenzamos a generar el código LaTeX

    s = \[r'\\begin{center}$\\displaystyle f(x)=' + r'{0}$'.format(latex(fun)) + r'\\end{center}'\]

    

    \# Primera línea de la tabla

    s.append(r'\\begin{center}\\begin{tabular}{r|r}$x$&$y$\\\\ \\hline')
# Bucle para generar los puntos de la tabla

for k in range(n):

s.append(r'${0}$&${1}$\\'.format(latex(xi[k]), latex(yi[k])))

# Cerramos la tabla

s.append(r'\end{tabular}\end{center}')

    return ''.join(s)

\\end{sagesilent}



% Usamos la función para generar la tabla

\\sagestr{tabla\_valores(x\^2 - 5\*x + 1, \[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2\])}

Thank you in advance for your time and support. Any suggestions or resources you could share would be most helpful.
Kind regards, Mario.

Please have a look at marked as a code sample. The source code of your question shows \ . Are they actually in your code or did you just add them so that one \ will show in your question?

Oh no, there are not in my code

@MarioGómez can you edit your post and replace the code or remove them? I tried to do it for you, but there are places where I'm not sure whether the double backslashes are in the original or not.

Related questions, that might also solve your problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472941/call-sage-in-texstudio-windows, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541256/sagetex-in-texstudio-define-a-new-build-tool
