# sagetex not drawing pictures

Tags: sagetex

Maybe someone aldready asked this, but I have the following problem.

I tried to compile an example I found here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483113/217249. I don't get any errors. I have sage installed and apparently sagetex.sty is known to pdflatex. However, I didn't get any pictures so far.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
    An elegant plot of the stream lines of the vector field \(\sin x \partial_x + \cos y \partial y\).
    \begin{sagesilent}
        x, y = var('x y')
    \end{sagesilent}
    \begin{center}
        \sageplot[width=\textwidth]{streamline_plot((sin(x), cos(y)), (x,-3,3), (y,-3,3))}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

And here is the "plot":
[image]

I'm not sure, maybe its not latex error at all...

Comment: Have you run `sage` on the `sagetex.sage` file `sagetex` has created for you? You need to actually run sage to do see the plot.

Comment: @gjkf Should I add sage into my chain (I'm using TeXstudio)?

Comment: Yes, you should. Sage should be run each time you modify any of your `sagetex` environments, so that the output is updated. How to do that? I'm not sure since I don't use TexStudio but I'm fairly certain that on Sagetex's wiki there's a guide for that.

Comment: @gjkf Thank you, it worked like a charm! Here is an answer explaining how to add sagetex to the texstudio default chain https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541256/sagetex-in-texstudio-define-a-new-build-tool

Comment: Happy to have helped! To make everything more organized, I'll answer your question, if you want you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, it's necessary to actually run `sage` on the file generated by `sagetex`. To do that either run it manually or integrate with your environment. To do so with TeXStudio use this answer: [sagetex in texstudio : define a new build tool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541256/sagetex-in-texstudio-define-a-new-build-tool)