# How do i use SageTex in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, sagetex

I just recently found the CAS-application SageMath. SageMath has a TeX plugin called [SageTex](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html), and I would like to use this with the TeX editor  [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/), however I am quite a noob, so I don't know how I add a command to run the TeX document through sagemath. Please help a newbie. Screenshots of the how-to would also greatly be appreciated :)

Comment: 1. Sagetex is a package for LaTeX; it won't work unless you have Sage installed on your computer. 2. If Sage is on your computer, compilation is 3 steps as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251459/strange-result-when-trying-to-use-sagetex). An IDE allows you to reduce the 3 step process to pressing a button, such as with TeXmaker [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251870/how-do-i-write-a-custom-command-to-enable-sage-in-texmaker). 3. Sagemath is now [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com/); sign up for a free account and you don't need Sage. This is the quickest way.

Comment: @DJP - regarding point 3 in your comment... SageMath is still SageMath. It's free software for mathematics, that can be installed on one's computer, or used online.  CoCalc is an online platform where one can use a remote computer running Ubuntu, with a lot of free software pre-installed, including, but not limited to, SageMath. It also has collaborative features and course management features. CoCalc started under the name SageMathCloud, and was renamed in part to avoid the confusion.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. Think the name change caused more confusion, at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation page

- [SageMath documentation: tutorial: using SageTeX](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html)

has the instructions on how to find the relevant files in your Sage installation and where to copy them so that they get picked up by LaTeX when you `\usepackage{sagetex}`.